# no contract code at given address

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity-0.8.x

I have a contract at `https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xDE30091Db14179f1D2243d56c980A941dA4E9651`

The transaction is sent to `https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0xa2b4c5de6d393be90a38d4f7d3d360dd1f748ad0028b0f3ef662aba1aac9be59`

Where I can clearly see the input data

```
Function: setItem(bytes32 key,bytes32 value) ***

MethodID: 0xf56256c7
[0]:  666f6f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
[1]:  6261720000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

This is a code snippet

```
    address, tx, instance, err := api.DeployWarehouse(auth, connection.Client)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Failed to deploy contract: %v", err)
        return "", "", err
    }
    fmt.Printf("Contract deployed at address %s with transaction hash %s\n", address.Hex(), tx.Hash().Hex())
    
    k := "foo"
    v := "bar"
    key := [32]byte{}
    value := [32]byte{}
    copy(key[:], k)
    copy(value[:], v)

    assignTx, err = instance.SetItem(auth2, key, value)
    if err == nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
    }

    result, err := instance.GetItem(nil, key) 
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)//<--no contract code at given address
    }
```

Any idea what causes this?

Comment: you are using wrong contract address, that's why it says "no code"

Comment: I am using the same instance from the deployed contract to read the contract. Basically I set and get with the same variable.
Can you please elaborate on how I get the wrong address?